# ScrollView not working on android 2.2 device

Tags: android, android-layout

I've a simple code :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtCustomerName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/customername" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtCustomerEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/customeremail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

  <!--    others -->
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The scroll view doesn't work with a Samsung GT-S5570 with android 2.2.1 (and with a bad screen resolution).

It works on a nexus 4 or a nexus 7 with android 4.4. And also with a Galaxy S on Android 2.3.3.

Any clue ? I have no idea why it doesn't work

Comment: define `doesn't work`

Comment: Can't scroll. No scrollbar and no touch scroll. Very strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try surrounding the ScrollView with a LinearLayout. This works for me everytime. Example, with my 'stuff' within the scrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip" android:gravity="top"
android:layout_gravity="top">

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/helpscroller" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="top" android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="1dip">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="top" android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="1dip">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dip" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/title" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18dip" android:padding="2dip"
                android:text="BTO/RSPB/BirdWatch Ireland/SOC/WOS"
                android:layout_gravity="top" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:padding="2dip" />

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="1dip">
            <Button android:id="@+id/helpButton" android:text="Help"
                android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/dismissButton" android:text="Done"
                android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```